# html add class to item without ID with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a class to a `<li>` using JavaScript, this is the html I have:

```
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">
    <input type="checkbox" name="categoryItems_option_1" value="1">&nbsp;
    <label for="categoryItems_option_1" class="selctAllBox">Select/Deselect All</label>
</li>
```

I cant use the "k-item" class because there is more then one of them.

I added the "selectAllBox" class like that:

```
$("label[for='categoryItems_option_1']").addClass("selctAllBox");
```

Is there a way to use something like parent or anything like that, to set the class?

Comment: set  `ID` to  `<li>` and then add class to this!!!

Comment: i think will have to add more information for people to understand that i cant do that

Comment: `$("label[for='categoryItems_option_1']").parent().addClass('your_class')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parent, like so:

```
$("label[for='categoryItems_option_1']").parent().addClass("TheClass");
```